# django appuser give duplicate key error while creating new superuser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

im getting this error while creating new superuser

> Heres the error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_auth_appuser_phone_key"
DETAIL:  Key (phone)=() already exists.
```

I know it is checking for unique phone number while also considering empty phone value and hence giving this error.

my question is how to resolve this

> Models.py:

```
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    class Gender(models.IntegerChoices):
        Male = 1, 'MALE'
        Female = 2, 'FEMALE'
        Other = 3, 'OTHER'

    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Gender.choices, null=True, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    doa = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def info(self):
        from user_auth.serializers import UserSerializer
        return UserSerializer(self).data

    @property
    def token(self):
        return RefreshToken.for_user(self)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since I don't have enough reputation to comment, I post my thoughts as an answer.

As seen here [Django unique nullable CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#field-options,)

if you want the phone field to be unique and be empty, you could use phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, null=True) so that when it's not provided it results to null instead of '' (empty string).

Since null != null, this might fix it.